# How to test when the end of an SMS message has been reached

Tags: sms, at-command

I am writing an application which acts on commands received via SMS (in Python, but the problem occurs in other languages).

[This page on the CMGL command](https://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgl-text-mode/) shows the following command and response:

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"
+CMGL: 1,"REC UNREAD","+31628870634",,"11/01/09,10:26:26+04"
This is text message 1
+CMGL: 2,"REC UNREAD","+31628870634",,"11/01/09,10:26:49+04"
This is text message 2
OK
```

Most implementations I have looked at look for a valid status such as OK or ERROR to detect the end of the response.

I am trying to find a way to determine the difference between this status code and the end of the message.

Otherwise it would be possible for a malicious sender to send a message of

```
Hello<CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>+CMGL: 1,(rest of fake message...)
```

Because I am receiving data on the serial port, there is no clear way to tell when I have reached the end of one message from the GSM board.

Could anyone point me to some information on the best practice here please? Other implementations I have seen do not seem to cover this issue.

The only idea I have had so far (but feels quite messy) is to keep reading until a timeout has been hit. Then check the number of OK / ERROR lines in the message and only accept the last.